# Lopping duplicate the first and last row in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
   id     a       b
    1     1       5
    2    -5       0
    3     0       5
    4     5       6
```

and i want to duplicate the first and last row of the dataframe:

```
   id     a       b
    1     1       5
    1     1       5
    2    -5       0
    3     0       5
    4     5       6
    4     5       6
```

but i have many dataframe in a list so i try using this code:

```
for df in list:
    pd.concat([df.head(1), df], axis=1)
    pd.concat([df.tail(1), df], axis=1)
```

and it doesn't work. can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with fixing

```
for i, df in enumerate(list):
    list[i] = pd.concat([df.head(1), df ,df.tail(1)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `df.take`

```
df_final = df.take([0,*range(len(df)),-1])

Out[852]:
   id  a  b
0   1  1  5
0   1  1  5
1   2 -5  0
2   3  0  5
3   4  5  6
3   4  5  6
```

For multiple `df`s, assign back on each iteration

```
for i, df in enumerate(list):
    list[i] = df.take([0,*range(len(df)),-1])
```

Comment: Nice one with take ~

Answer (score 2):

You can try,

```
output = []
for df in l:
    output.append(pd.concat([df.iloc[:1,:], df, df.iloc[-1:,:]]))
```